# CURL | Upload multiple html files to confluence

Tags: curl, confluence, confluence-rest-api

I need to upload html files from Jenkins workspace to confluence via CURL command.

Script used:-

```
stage('Publish to Confluence') {
          steps {
          withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'confluence', usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD')]) {
          sh '''
          curl -v -S -u $USERNAME:$PASSWORD -X POST -H "X-Atlassian-Token: no-check" -F "file_0=@code/pydoc/manage_connections.html" "https://alm-group.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/PROJECT/pages/830833705/PyDoc"
          '''
          }}}
```

Issue is- It is uploading single file as a attachment. I need to upload bunch of files but I am not able to do it.

I followed below link but unable to crack it.
https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/confluence/rest/#api-content-get

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not a Jenkins question at all.

This is actually a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599957/upload-multiple-files-to-php-server-using-curl-command-line).

For many files just duplicated the -F with @.

```
curl -F "image=@file1.gif" -F "image2=@file2.gif"  http://localhost:8888/web/Upload.php
```